# Why do I have to unplug the STM32F4 discovery card to update program?

Tags: usb, arm, stm32

I am starting working on embedded programs using the STM32F4 discovery board and the Atollic Lite PC software.

Every time I edit, recompile and attempt to download the revised program,  it tells me the ST-LINK interface won't work unless I unplug and re-plug the USB cable.  This is annoying because my last computer was ruined by plugging and unplugging the USB cables millions of times.

Is there an easy work-around for this, or something I am not doing to keep the ST-link connection between the IDE and the board healthy ?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging from the dev board instead?

Comment: Do you have the correct settings for the programmer/debugger? Have you tried a different USB port?

Answer (score 1):

Wreck a $5 passive hub instead of a $500 computer!

Or find better upload tools...

If the newest release of the Atollic tools don't solve your problem, search "open source STM32 upload tool" - there may be an open source alternative, along the lines of "avrdude" for another family of CPUs.

You can still use the current tool chain for program development, as long as it can produce a standard executable format like ".elf" or Intel Hex, that the new uploader tool can recognize.

Comment: There's stlink for an open source alternative, I'm not sure it works in Windows though. It's primarily meant for Linux, but there's mention of mingw32 in commit notes? Might be worth checking.
https://github.com/texane/stlink

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that problem with the Atollic software or the Rowley CrossWorks tools. Try downloading the current Atollic software (3.30).